# Aptana 3 automatic download/upload

Tags: aptana

I'm trying to switch from Dreamweaver to a real IDE and trying Aptana as a likely candidate, however i'm stuck on how to get it's FTP to behave the way it did in DW.

Basically when I open a file in a project, it needs to automatically download from the FTP connection, before opening it.

The Deployment Settings > Automatically Sync in Both Direction doesn't seem to work, the only option of those 3 that works is "Sync from my machine to remote", which basically uploads the file on save - which is great, but I also need it to download when I open the file as well.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Aptana Studio does not run file synchronization on it's opening, only on save.
[There is a ticket for this feature](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2953) which you could vote for.

Alternatively, you should be able to open, edit and save files directly from FTP connection.